# Python Linter to catch user shadowed function names

Tags: python, mypy, pylint, linter, ruff

Assume the following scenario:

```
def my_decorator(func):
   @functools.wraps(func)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       # Code
   return wrapper

def f():
   # function code
   return

f = my_decorator(f)
```

`f =  my_decorator(f)` shadows the function `f` and that will lead to unexpected behavior on `f()` calls down the line.

**Linters that I tried so far and results:**

- **MyPy:** Can catch the shadowing if `f` changes type completely (ex. `f = "I am a string now"`) but not the shadowing in question.
- **Pylint:** Same as **MyPy**
- **Ruff:** Same as **MyPy**

Also all the linters mentioned are able to catch built-in variable shadowing.
*So the linters are failing in the scenario of interest because `f` ultimately doesn't change type passing though the decorator method.*

**Questions:**

- Is there any tweak that I am missing for any of those linters than can possibly make them more pedantic/strict?
- Is there any alternative that may work and I have not considered?

Comment: Submit a feature request to mypy and see their response; maybe there's a reason why they don't do this (maybe there's a lot of code which decorates functions after they are defined?). mypy definitely catches attempts at reassignment for classes, and already catches attempts at defining functions/classes with the same name multiple times (e.g. if you `def f` twice in the same module at the module-level).